# \newtheorem setup in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm wondering how to force LaTeX to \noident "Example 1.1." in my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{ams symb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3.0cm, rmargin=2.5cm}
\linespread{1.3}

\newtheorem{abc}{Example}[chapter]

\begin{document}
     \chapter{Important chapter}
     \section{Important section}
        \begin{abc} 
         \begin{enumerate}[a)]
             \noindent
             \item  
              $a^2 + b^2 = c^2,$
              \item 
              $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2.$
          \end{enumerate}
       \end{abc}
\end{document}
```

There is any solution for that. Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3.0cm, rmargin=2.5cm}
\linespread{1.3}

\newtheorem{abc}{Example}[chapter]

\begin{document}
     \chapter{Important chapter}
     \section{Important section}
        \begin{abc}
        \mbox{}
         \begin{enumerate}[a)]
             \item  
              $a^2 + b^2 = c^2,$
              \item 
              $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2.$
          \end{enumerate}
       \end{abc}
\end{document}
```

[image]